# FEM analyis of flow in a hydrocyclone

Tags: finite-element-method, fluid-dynamics, stl-format

I am interested in solving the flow in a hydrocyclone (steady Navier Stokes equation). I have an STL file of the 3D geometry. My question is how to extract the *internal geometry* of the hydrocyclone for the flow field analaysis.  Mathematica has no problem reading the STL file. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you extend your question so that we understand what are you talking about?

Answer (score 6):

Depending on what source generated the STL, converting it to a usable CFD geometry can be quite difficult.  Since the geometry of a hydrocyclone is quite simple, I recommend using [OpenCascadeLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCascadeLink/tutorial/UsingOpenCascadeLink.html).

Here is a simple sketch of the fluid surfaces of a hydrocyclone I downloaded from GrabCAD.

[image: Cyclone Sketch]

If you study the OpenCascade tutorial, you can build this geometry with the following workflow:

```
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
polypts = 1/1000 {
    {0, 0, -120},
    {2.4, 0, -120},
    {4.8, 0, 0},
    {10.5, 0, 0},
    {30, 0, 295},
    {30, 0, 350},
    {19, 0, 350},
    {19, 0, 312},
    {8, 0, 302},
    {8, 0, 402},
    {0, 0, 402}
    };
inletpts = 1/1000 {{30, -40, 342}, {19, 0, 325}};
pp = Polygon@polypts;
shape = OpenCascadeShape[pp];
axis = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
sweep = OpenCascadeShapeRotationalSweep[shape, axis];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[sweep];
(* Convert Shape Faces To Solid *)
shapecyclone = OpenCascadeShape[bmesh];
shapeinlet = OpenCascadeShape[Cuboid @@ inletpts];
OpenCascadeShapeType /@ {shapecyclone, shapeinlet}
union = OpenCascadeShapeUnion [shapeinlet, shapecyclone];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[union];
groups = bmesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"];
temp = Most[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[groups])]];
colors = ColorData["BrightBands"][#] & /@ temp;
bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm /@ colors]]
bmesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Cyclone]

Generally, hydrocyclones operate in the turbulent regime and I have not come across any steady-state turbulence models implemented in *Mathematica*.  Good luck!

## Update

Just to show that the device does indeed function as a particle classifier, I conducted a simulation with another solver.  The animation below shows larger diameter ${\color{Red} {Red} }$ Particles are more directed to the bottom outlet and the smaller White Particles exit out the top.

[image: Particle tracing]

Currently, *Mathematica* lacks boundary layer meshing capability, which can dramatically reduce model size.